# Is sudo crontab -e and sudo cat /etc/crontab the relevant one for cron?

Tags: debian, cron

```
$ sudo cat /etc/crontab
# ...comment lines elided... 
0 0,12 * * * root sleep 1347 && certbot renew -q --post-hook 'sudo reboot'
```

`sudo crontab -e` shows

```
13 0,12 * * * root sleep 1347 && certbot renew -q
```

This VM is a simple default-configured Google Compute Engine VM with Debian Buster. I am logged in  as a user joshua, but note that sudo does not require entering a password.

Which one (or perhaps both?) shows what cron actually does?   What is the recommended way to edit the cron config, `crontab -e` or directly editing some file, e.g. with `sudo vi`?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and clarify. What is the first crontab you show? And are you _sure_ the second is what you see with `sudo crontab -e`? There shouldn't be a `user` field in that file. It looks like both lines you show are actually from `/etc/crontab`. What do you mean by "what cron actually does"? Cron will run everything it is told to run. And no, `sudo crontab -e` will show root's user-crontab, not yours.

Comment: I edited it (the first line had been "swallowed" by triple tilde.

Comment: Thank you. Does "everything it is told to run" include both the configurations above?

Comment: Thanks! So, the output of `sudo crontab -e` is wrong, only `/etc/crontab` should have a user as the 6th field, so the line should be `13 0,12 * * * sleep 1347 && certbot renew -q`.

Comment: "are you sure the second is what you see with sudo crontab -e?" Yes, I just retried.
"There shouldn't be a user field"
This is a simple default-configured Google Compute Engine VM, I am logged in  as a user joshua, but note that sudo does not require entering a password

Comment: "sudo crontab -e will show root's user-crontab, not yours." OK, so what is the difference between these two configurations?

Comment: "the output of sudo crontab -e is wrong." OK, so that probably means that  edited it-- wrongly.

Comment: `crontab -e` verifies your edits, refuses to install a crontab with errors, and signals the cron daemon that it should refresh its internal copy of the new file. `vi crontab` does none of those things, and is inviting disaster. Also, `crontab -l` will list your crontab file. Hint: crontab default editor is `nano` on my box -- `EDITOR=vi crontab -e` is my friend here.

Comment: Thank you. So there is never a  need to edit `/etc/crontab`

Answer (score 7):

The commented lines in `/etc/crontab` will tell you:

```
# /etc/crontab: system-wide crontab
# Unlike any other crontab you don't have to run the `crontab'
# command to install the new version when you edit this file
# and files in /etc/cron.d. These files also have username fields,
# that none of the other crontabs do.
```

`/etc/crontab` and `/etc/cron.d/*` define the system-wide crons. They have a user field in front of the command to be executed.

With `sudo crontab -e`, you edit `root`'s crontab file which is located at `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/root` (for `debian`, [different location in other OS](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/196009/location-of-the-crontab-file)).

Note, that you should never edit the files directly, but use `crontab -e` command.

---

The user's crontab file should not include the user name, so it should read:

```
13 0,12 * * * sleep 1347 && certbot renew -q
```